# Chaining data without iteration

Tags: python, recursion

I have a large set of From/To pairs that represent a hierarchy of connected nodes.  As an example, the hierarchy:

```
     4 -- 5 -- 8
    / 
   2 --- 6 - 9 -- 10
  /           \ 
 1              -- 11
  \
   3 ----7
```

is encapsulated as:

```
{(11, 9), (10, 9), (9, 6), (6, 2), (8, 5), (5, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (7, 3)}
```

I'd like to be able to create a function that returns all nodes upstream of a given node, e.g.:

```
nodes[2].us
> [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

My actual set of nodes is in the tens of thousands, so I'd like to be able to very quickly return a list of all upstream nodes without having to perform recursion over the entire set each time I want to get an upstream set.

This is my best attempt so far, but it doesn't get beyond two levels up.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, fr, to):
        self.fr = fr
        self.to = to
        self.us = set()

def build_hierarchy(nodes):
    for node in nodes.values():
        if node.to in nodes:
            nodes[node.to].us.add(node)
    for node in nodes.values():
        for us_node in node.us.copy():
            node.us |= us_node.us
    return nodes

from_to = {(11, 9), (10, 9), (9, 6), (6, 2), (8, 5), (5, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (7, 3), (1, 0)}
nodes = {fr: Node(fr, to) for fr, to in from_to} # node objects indexed by "from"
nodes = build_hierarchy(nodes)

print [node.fr for node in nodes[2].us]
> [4, 6, 5, 9]
```

Comment: In your example, what about 4, 5 and 8? Why are they not included in the results?

Comment: are you bound to this representation of your problem?

Comment: Is there some reason that a standard DFS/BFS won't work?

Comment: If ever node has 1 head a dictionary would be much better suited then the problem becomes very easy.

Comment: BFS/DFS python examples:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576723-dfs-and-bfs-graph-traversal/

Comment: In your title, do you mean with or without iteration, as if you want to avoid recursion (question body), it might be hard to avoid iteration (title)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - 4, 5, and 8 should be included in the results (added).

What I meant by without iteration/recursion is that I'd like avoid having to iterate over the entire set of nodes each time I query upstream from a single node.  As in, I don't want to execute a recursive or iterative search every single time I query the upstream nodes from a given node.

Comment: If a you find yourself doing many of these types of traversals (e.g. using simple BFS/DFS algorithm) over a tree or graph that's static (isn't changing between calcs), then implement a memoization strategy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) via a secondary data structure to avoid re-calculating upstream nodes for nodes you've previously visited/calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show two ways of doing this. First, we'll simply modify your `us` attribute to intelligently compute and cache the results of a descendant lookup. Second, we'll use a graph library, `networkx`.

I'd really recommend you go with the graph library if your data naturally has graph structure. You'll save yourself a lot of hassle that way.

## Caching `us` nodes property

You can make your `us` attribute a property, and cache the results of previous lookups:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.parent = None
        self.children = set()
        self._upstream = set()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node({})".format(self.name)

    @property
    def upstream(self):
        if self._upstream:
            return self._upstream
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                self._upstream.add(child)
                self._upstream |= child.upstream
            return self._upstream
```

Note that I'm using a slightly different representation than you. I'll create the graph:

```
import collections

edges = {(11, 9), (10, 9), (9, 6), (6, 2), (8, 5), (5, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (7, 3)}
nodes = collections.defaultdict(lambda: Node())

for node, parent in edges:
    nodes[node].name = node
    nodes[parent].name = parent
    nodes[node].parent = nodes[parent]
    nodes[parent].children.add(nodes[node])
```

and I'll lookup the upstream nodes for node 2:

```
>>> nodes[2].upstream
{Node(5), Node(4), Node(11), Node(9), Node(6), Node(8), Node(10)}
```

Once the nodes upstream of 2 are computed, they won't be recomputed if you call, for example `nodes[1].upstream`. If you make any changes to your graph, then, the upstream nodes will be incorrect.

## Using `networkx`

If we use `networkx` to represent our graph, a lookup of all of the descendants of a node is very simple:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> from_to = [(11, 9), (10, 9), (9, 6), (6, 2), (8, 5), (5, 4), (4, 2), 
               (2, 1), (3, 1), (7, 3), (1, 0)]
>>> graph = nx.DiGraph(from_to).reverse()
>>> nx.descendants(graph, 2)
{4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

This doesn't fully answer your question, which seemed to be about optimizing the lookup of descendants so work wasn't repeated on subsequent calls. However, for all we know, `networkx.descendants` might do some intelligent caching.

So this is what I'd suggest: avoid optimizing prematurely and use the libraries. If `networkx.descendants` is too slow, then you might investigate the `networkx` code to see if it caches lookups. If not, you can build your own caching lookup using more primitive `networkx` functions. My bet is that `networkx.descendants` will work just fine, and you won't need to go through the extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will calculate the entire upstream list for a single node:

```
def upstream_nodes(start_node):
    result = []
    current = start_node
    while current.to:  # current.to == 0 means we're at the root node
        result.append(current.to)
        current = nodes[current.to]
    return result
```

You've said that you don't want to iterate over the entire set of nodes each time you query an upstream, but this won't: it will just query that nodes' parent, and its parent, all the way to the root. So if the node is four levels down, it will make four dictionary lookups.

Or, if you want to be really clever, here's a version that will only make each parent lookup once, then store that lookup in the Node object's `.us` attribute so you never have to calculate the value again. (If your nodes' parent links aren't going to change after the graph has been created, this will work -- if you change your graph, of course, it won't).

```
def caching_upstream_nodes(start_node, nodes):
    # start_node is the Node object whose upstream set you want
    # nodes is the dictionary you created mapping ints to Node objects
    if start_node.us:
        # We already calculated this once, no need to re-calculate
        return start_node.us
    parent = nodes.get(start_node.to)
    if parent is None:
        # We're at the root node
        start_node.us = set()
        return start_node.us
    # Otherwise, our upstream is our parent's upstream, plus the parent
    parent_upstream = caching_upstream_nodes(parent, nodes)
    start_node.us = parent_upstream.copy()
    start_node.us.add(start_node.to)
    return start_node.us
```

One of those two functions should be what you're looking for. (NOTE: Exercise a little bit of caution when running these, as I just wrote them but haven't invested the time to test them. I believe the algorithm is correct, but there's always a chance that I made a basic error in writing it.)

Comment: These seem to be going what I would call downstream rather than upstream.  I guess there's no way to go up without recursion.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Then you'll need to make two passes. First, use `caching_upstream_nodes` (renamed to `downstream`) to calculate each node's ancestors. Then loop through the nodes one more time, and for each node, take all of its ancestors and add the current node to their upstream set. Essentially, what you tried to do with `build_hierarchy ` in the OP, but using the first pass to calculate *all* ancestors. Then the second pass will correctly record every node's upstream list.